# WPF Slider - Setting focus on slider on clicking anywhere on its Track

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have requirement that if user clicks anywhere on slider, it should get the logical focus. It works, if I drag the thumb of the slider. But I am facing an issue when I click on Track(Increase and Decrease repeat button - Red box shown in below image), slider is not getting focus. Please note that I have set IsMoveToPointEnabled to true.

[image]

Couple of things that I tried:

1. Tried by setting everything Focusable=True in slider [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
2. Has workaround - Handling ValueChanged event and setting focus explicity on slider when value changes.

Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

```
<Slider IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
            x:Name="testSlider"
            Focusable="True"
            Minimum="0"
            Maximum="1">
        <Slider.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Slider">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>

            </Style>
        </Slider.Style>
    </Slider>
```

Comment: It works fine without any override of template in small app.

Comment: @RohitVats: So you are saying that by simply using Slider control, when you click on Increase/Decrease button track, IsFocused of slider becomes true? This doesn't seems to be working for me. Updated the question with the code that I have in sample app.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove **`IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"`** from your slider and posted code works fine.

---

**UPDATE**

Setting `IsMoveToPointEnabled` to `True` eat up the mouse down event since rectangle inside template used it to move to specific point. Hence, it never get tunnel to slider and it doesn't get focus.

However, **`MouseUp`** event is raised properly so what you can do is hook that event and manually put focus on the slider.

**XAML**

```
<Slider IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
        x:Name="testSlider"
        MouseUp="testSlider_MouseUp"
        Focusable="True"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="100">
    <Slider.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Slider.Style>
</Slider>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void testSlider_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((Slider)sender).Focus();
}
```

Comment: I can't, as I want the feature of slider moving to point where user has clicked on slider track.

Comment: I have updated an answer for another approach. See if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for the explanation. I was aware that rectangle was eating  up focus but thought .Net might have provided something for this. I am able to fix this issue by adding ValueChanged event and also by creating custom slider control & overriding previewmouseleftbuttondown event handler, but I was looking for more of Xaml solution. So I think, workaround is the only solution to this problem :(

Comment: Yeah you can't do that only XAML way since there is no way from XAML to re-route the event which got handled somewhere down the visual tree. So, yes workaround is only solution to your problem. I would suggest you not to use `ValueChanged` since it will result in memory leak which you can read about [here](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/).